Should we activate Mathjax?
Mathjax is a way of rendering mathematical equations using markup. I'd like it to be enabled on this site as it is on math and physics? Sometimes it's very hard to answer certain questions without the use of some mathematical notation. 
Should Mathjax be activated for this site?

It would help if you pointed to the questions where this would be beneficial (preferably in your feature request)

@TimPost, Here's one from me personally.
